# DNN Active Directory Authentication module works first time but doesn't work after that

Tags: active-directory, dotnetnuke

I am using DNN version 7.4. I successfully installed [DNN Active Directory Authentication module 5.0.6](https://dnnauthad.codeplex.com/releases/view/103609). It works first time when I try to login. After the login I can see a new user has been created. Next time, I try to login, I get an error message which is "Critical Error. Please see the event viewer". If I delete the user from "Users > Manage Users", I am able to login. Next time, the problem comes again and I can't login. 
The event viewer content is given below.

```
Request information: 
Request URL: http://localhost:84/default.aspx 
Request path: /default.aspx 
User host address: ::1 
User:  
Is authenticated: False 
Authentication Type:  
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 

Thread information: 
Thread ID: 7 
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 
Is impersonating: False 
Stack trace:    at 
DotNetNuke.Professional.Authentication.ActiveDirectory.HttpModules.AuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object s, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Any idea how to solve this problem. I tried to download the source file but I can't open it using VS 2012 or 2013.

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar issue. You have to make some changes to the `web.config` in the membership provider tag as seen in the following lines.

```
- enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
- passwordFormat="Encrypted"
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! Would you mind adding to your answer why this will solve the problem?

Comment: check this:http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/488876/scope/posts/this-membership-provider-has-not-been-configured-to-support-password-retrieval

Comment: It would be great if you include the important parts as quotes in your answer.

Comment: I hope so, but actually I'm new in DNN